Get 'ExponentPushToken' in Android inside the Expo Go simulator , but in built apk version - I got it {"code": "ERR_UNEXPECTED"}
When I call (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data in Expo Go on Android, everything is working, including Push Notification.
But, build version of apk throw only an exception: {"code": "ERR_UNEXPECTED"}  when I try to get push token: (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data
Have no clue how to debug and fix it :(
P.S. Android FireBase already set up.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Resolved... :)
Answer it here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22674#issuecomment-1577806958
